# html keep text together with different fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, spacing

two CSS settings :

```css
h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

h6red{
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #ff0000;
 font-weight: 400;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h6red>LE CHIC</h6red><h6> jouw partner in kleur</h6>
```

The output is on two lines, can i prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Erwin

Answer (score 0):

`<h6red>` isn't valid markup. But what you're looking for is display. Add `display:inline-block;` to both of the above and they will stay on one line.

Comment: For some reason, the OP is using trying to use a custom element, where as a simple class would do the trick.  For reference, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-custom-elements-20131024/

Comment: well, you would need a class and another span or something. either way, he'll need two tags. and you shouldn't make assumptions. for all you know he could be using some less strict version of xml or something.. idk, but there could be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Marc Audet, `<h6red>` isn't valid HTML and therefore we shoud start there. Header tags are `<h1>`,`<h2>`,`<h3>`,`<h4>`,`<h5>` and `<h6>` with no other variations other than the number change. the smaller the number, the larger the text gets. Anything else wont be properly read by the browser as a heading.

With that being said, here's what I'd do.

Using a `<span>` tag, you could isolate(or 'wrap') one word within a sentence and decorate the`<span>` in CSS. This would keep the text inline while adding the style. My recommendation would be use a classname on the `<span>` to allow its use for different things later, unless you only plan to use it once. I would suggest:

```
<h6>
  <span class="makeRed">LE CHIC</span>jouw partner in kleur
</h6>
```

along with this CSS:

```
h6{
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.makeRed{
  color: #f39999;
}
```